# Why to use ajax to send a PostgreSQL query to a server?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, postgresql

I have a web application where I actually use JQuery and Ajax in order to send a query to my database.
My script is something as simple as this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var datastr = id; // get the value inserted in text
            var ajaxurl = 'run.php', // script to run
            data =  {datastr:datastr}; // data to pass
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response){...//do something
```

Making some improvements in my script it crossed my mind this: do I really need to make an Ajax request to send this query to the database or I can just use something as simple as the [PHP function for PostgreSQL to do that](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php)?
Ofcource I know that Ajax is all about asynchronous communication but I want to know what would be the best practice in a situation like this. Is using Ajax in this case an overkill?

Comment: Can't be answered in general, I think. It depends on what you want from your application. You can't use php function on a client side without reloading the whole page, that's where ajax comes in.

Comment: This question is not clear. Are you aware that the Ajax script us executing a PHP script anyway? That script is most probably using PostgreSQL or PDO anyway.

Comment: The only reason I can see to do this on document load, is when the generation of the data takes a long time and you want to show the page already. Otherwise you are just slowing things down by making an extra - unnecessary - request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do I really need to make an Ajax request to send this query to the
>   database or I can just use something as simple as the PHP function for
>   PostgreSQL to do that

Well actually it does not have the same goal. As you may know, Ajax is client-side meanwhile PHP is server-side. If you want to send your request without refreshing your webpage, then you would need asynchroneous request like Ajax does. Else, PHP fit your need.